# What is the javascript equivalent of numpy argsort?

Tags: javascript, numpy

I want to sort the imgUrl array by click count. I have two arrays.

```
clickCount = [5,2,4,3,1]
imgUrl     = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg']
```

In numpy it is easy. I use `order = np.argsort(clickCount)` then I create another array `newArray = [imgUrl[i] for i in order]`.

How do I achieve the same effect in javascript (preferably vanilla)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) also known as Decorate-Sort-Undecorate (DSU) in python.

**DSU:**

1. Decorate - Use [Array#Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to enrich each item in the array with the needed sort data
2. Sort - sort using the added data
3. Undecorate - extract the sorted data using Array#map again

**Demo:**

```js
const dsu = (arr1, arr2) => arr1
  .map((item, index) => [arr2[index], item]) // add the args to sort by
  .sort(([arg1], [arg2]) => arg2 - arg1) // sort by the args
  .map(([, item]) => item); // extract the sorted items

const clickCount = [5,2,4,3,1];
const imgUrl = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'];

const result = dsu(imgUrl, clickCount);
  
console.log(result);
```

*thanks to [dankal444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4601890/dankal444) for the refactor to the function*

Comment: No problem, but my point was to make the function similar to `numpy.argsort` - with single array as an input and indices as an output. Addressing `What is the javascript equivalent of numpy argsort?` rather than OP specific problem.

Comment: I've made it more generic, but if you want to make it similar to `numpy.argsort` you'll need to add it to the Array's prototype. Your version wasn't actually working because you've ignored the 2n array. 

You should create a new answer which updates the Array prototype, and create a snippet as well, so you'll know that it works.

Comment: Well, it is good to add such function to prototype but why is it *necessary*? It isn't a "my version", it is just something to add to your answer. And it "wasn't working" because it wasn't supposed to work for OP problem. It is just a function similar to `numpy.argsort`, based on your original answer. If you really do not find it suitable I will add my answer.

Comment: It's not actually. My answer specifically deals with sorting one array using another. You have created a version that returns the original indexes. You are using DSU, but in a very specific way. That's another answer. No need to add anything to the prototype to do just that. My bad.

Comment: Could you explain how `([arg1], [arg2]) => arg2 - arg1` works? I see that it stands for the comparefunction in [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but I am not sure how it applies to `[arr2[index], item]`.

Comment: Sort compares between two items. Since each item was mapped to be `[arr2[index], item])`, we assign `arr2[index]` of the items we compare to `arg1` and `arg2`.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, here's my solution to the actual answer (providing `argsort` function), by expanding on Ori's answer with DSU.
Since sort is by default taking the first element, so implementing it as DSU is merely adding an index, sorting it, then taking the indices.

```js
let decor = (v, i) => [v, i];          // set index to value
let undecor = a => a[1];               // leave only index
let argsort = arr => arr.map(decor).sort().map(undecor);

clickCount = [5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
imgUrl = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg']

order = argsort(clickCount);
newArray = order.map(i => imgUrl[i])

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: in 50 chars: `argsort=`
`a=>a.map(d).sort().map(u);d=(v,i)=>[v,i];u=i=>i[1]`

Comment: `a=>a.map((v,i)=>[v,i]).sort().map(i=>i[1])` : 43 chars

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach (like @Ori Drori's code) is always a charm to watch, but in this case, you only need to re-arrange an array's items. I believe that there is a simpler way to go and is a much easier code to read.

```js
const clickCount = [5,2,4,3,1];
const imgUrl = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'];

sortByArrayRefOrder = (data, orderRefArr) => {
 let orderedArr = [], i=0;
 orderRefArr.map( o => { orderedArr[o-1] = data[i++]});
 return orderedArr.reverse();
}

console.log ( sortByArrayRefOrder(imgUrl, clickCount) );
```

Comment: No, sorry, if my example is misleading. The click count is the number of clicks, not an ordered ref. Click count can also be like this `const clickCount = [5323,23545,4333,34,123];`

Comment: Oh well, in this case @Ori Drori's answer is the perfect answer! Sorry for the mess up