# Sorting two arrays according specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, methods

What I'm trying to do is ordering 2 arrays lets say...

```js
let C = [10, 5, 6, 7]
let M = [8, 9, 2, 5]
```

The first array should stay as it is, but the second needs to be orderer so the output should go like this

```js
[10, 5, 6, 7]
[9, 2, 5, 8]
```

Basically, i need to order the second array so that the max value matches the max value of the other array.

Please take into account that the first array should stay the same, so i cant reorder both, just the second

To clarify, each array item is a box with that amount of coins and multipliers. One array is coins and the other multipliers.

You can't change the position of the coin boxes, but you can move the multiplier so you can get the max amount of coins. But you can't move the coin boxes from their position.

What i've discover is that in order to get the max amount of coins, you need to multiply the highest possible value, with the highest posible value of the other table. so te correct order would be something like

```js
[1,3,2,4]
[5,7,6,8]
```

and the values in example are

```js
[5 3 7 1]
[1 4 3 9]
//expected output
[4 3 9 1]
```

Comment: You need to explain more the ordering logic and show your attempt to solve the problem

Comment: as @MajedBadawi said, the idea is really not clear, you said "the maximum should match the maximum of the other array", but i did not see that in the two examples ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to correlate the two arrays by matching the highest number from `C` to the highest at `M`, and so on until the smallest.

To do so create a new array of indexes (`order`), map `arr1`, add the index to each item, an then sort the array (I chose descending order).

Now clone `arr2` and sort it in the same sort order you've used for `C` (descending order) to get the `sorted` array.

Now reduce the `order` array to another array, take the item with the same index `i` from `sorted`, and put it in the index `idx` taken from the `order` array.

```js
const fn = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const order = arr1
    .map((n, i) => [n, i])
    .sort(([n1], [n2]) => n2 - n1)
    .map(([, i]) => i)

  const sorted = [...arr2].sort((n1, n2) => n2 - n1)

  return order.reduce((acc, idx, i) => (acc[idx] = sorted[i], acc), [])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(
  [10, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 2, 5]
))) // [9, 2, 5, 8]

// [2,0,1,3]

console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(
  [5, 3, 7, 1],
  [1, 4, 3, 9]
))) // [4, 3, 9, 1]

console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(
  [5, 4],
  [7, 2]
))) // [7, 2]

console.log(JSON.stringify(fn(
  [11, 17, 39],
  [7, 5, 3]
))) // [3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: That looks correct, but i need to be able to use it with different arrays with different lengths (of course, between them they have the same length)

Comment: @DiegoVillafañe what makes you think this solution would not work for other length arrays?

Comment: @DiegoVillafañe - as long as the two arrays have the same length, this would work.

Comment: I just tried with other array and i didn't get the expected output, sorry this is my firs time asking and i'm kinda nervous, also english is not my native language

Comment: Please add the other arrays, and the expected output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! Where can I read a little bit to understand better what you did?

Comment: To get the indexes in the correct order I've used a variation of [DSU sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622486/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-numpy-argsort). You can read more about `Array.map()` in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: hey, it's not working as intended, let me edit the question to be more clear

Comment: Edit the question and not the answer.

Comment: @DiegoVillafañe - found the problem and fixed. The problem was in the building the array back. You need to take the item with the same index, but put it in the original index of the current item.

Comment: You did! Thank you so so very much! Again i would like to ask how can i understand it better, i get the methods but sort confuses me specially the conditions inside

Comment: I'm mapping the original array to an array of arrays. The sub-arrays are pairs of `[number, index]`. When I sort, I use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the numbers (1st item in sub-array), and then when I map again, I use destructuring to take the index (2nd item in sub-array).